# mysql: altered function but stays old function

Tags: mysql, function, alter

I changed a column name in a table, and i needed to change a function for it. So i changed the function. But it still runs the old function! it gives me :

```
"Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'avDoctorID' in 'where clause'"
```

and i'm sure i changed the function because if i see the function itself it is the new one! how can this be?

i did this in mysql workbench, and if i see the function in any other program it show the new function, but gives the same error when i try to run it.

This is the query to run it

```
select FNC_CreateAppointment(8,1,"2012-08-06","15:30:00","something");
```

And this it the function itself:

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `fnc_CreateAppointment`(clid int,calid int,appdate date,apptime time,commentaar varchar(3000)) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
declare succeeded boolean;
declare id2 int;
declare id int;
declare dagweek int;
Declare afwezig int;
set afwezig = 0;
set dagweek = Dayofweek(appdate);
set id =0;
set id2 = 0;
set succeeded = false;
select availableID into id from tbl_available where AVdays = dagweek and AVHours = apptime and avCalendarID = calid


;
if id > 0
then

select appointmentID into id2 from tbl_appointment where  appointmentDate = appdate and appointmentTime = apptime and CalendarID = calid;

if id2 = 0
then

select AbsentID into afwezig from tbl_absent where abHoliday = appdate and abAbsent = apptime and abCalendarID = calid;
if afwezig = 0 then

insert into tbl_appointment(clientId,Calendarid,appointmentDate,appointmenttime,remark)
Values
(clid,calid,appdate,apptime,commentaar);

set succeeded = true;
end if;

end if;


end if;

return succeeded;

END
```

the error returned is:

```
call db_demo.FNC_CreateAppointment(8,1,"2012-08-06","15:30:00","something") Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'avDoctorID' in 'where clause'
```

'avDoctorID' is the old column

Comment: Need some more info. Can you show the query?

Comment: i editet my first post with the query

Comment: In the function itself you have it defined as fnc_CreateAppointment() but then you're calling fnc_CreateAppointment2(). Which one should it be?

Comment: yeah i edited it, i'm sorry it's just fnc_CreateAppointment()

Comment: instead of doing `CREATE FUNCTION` what happens if you do `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`?

Comment: @schoen Hmm could it be the case of the function you are calling? You define it as `fnc` but call it as `FNC`. Just thinking out loud, haven't tried it

Comment: @mattedgod nope it's the same :(

Comment: @schoen That is puzzling. Try removing the function so that your query says "no function defined" then add it again.

Comment: You might need to DROP the function first and then run the CREATE again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to drop the function first and then run the CREATE statement again.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `<function_name>`
```

Comment: well this didn't work, but i dropped the whole database and imported it back, that worked!